# Liferay inter portlet communication

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, however after hours of research, I was unable to find a solution to my two issues:

1. Communication between portlets on the same page (using **jsr286**, public render parameter). The main problem here is using `AJAX` for the `IPC`, so that the communication stays server-side, but the page doesn't refresh.
2. The second problem I have is, how do I redirect from the first to a second `jsp` page, while passing a variable back end to the `java` file of the portlet on the second page?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: For next time: Please don't ask two questions at once. That way it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Comment: HI @TobiasLiefke thanks for the tip! I was aware of that, however due to the fact that the common topic is inter portlet communication and there is very poor documentation on Liferay in general, it might be beneficial to have two similar questions answered in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad. 1 Have you tried following document explaining idea of IPC Mechanism? (second section of document)

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication

Basically idea is pretty simple and I have created some portlets using it back then.

Ad. 2 Correct me if I am wrong, as I understand, you want to pass some parameters while redirection? Well, just pass these parameters to response object in method invoking redirection and you will be able to receive them in your second method. Here is part of code passing some parameters from Action phase to Render phase which is responsible for presenting view result.

```
    response.setRenderParameter(CURRENT_PAGE_PARAM, currentPage);
    response.setRenderParameter(DELTA_PARAM, deltaParam);
    response.setRenderParameter(ACTION_PARAM, "filterData");
```

Another idea can be storing your information in session model if this is shared between multiple views.

Comment: 1. I have used that document as a reference, however the main problem I have is that the page refreshes after Public-render-parameter Inter-portlet Communication, it has to be done without page refresh.
2. Will try that, would you be able to link me to a good tutorial explaining the redirection process and how to pass the parameters? Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: What is the exact case of redirection? User is using some link to redirect from one page to another in single portlet scope, or more specified situation? By the way, are you using Spring or just extends MVCPortlet class for your controller?

Comment: I'm using MVCPortlet class, should I be using Spring? The user clicks on a link on one page, that should bring him to another page, while passing a parameter to the back-end of a portlet the second page, which gets its contents based on that parameter.

Comment: I have bigger experience using Spring MVC however this shouldn't be important in your case. Basically you don't need redirection but just simple render method which will present different view for a user. Look for simple tutorials showing how to create portlet allowing user to present list and details for any abstract model.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for good examples of Liferay portlets, check out this great GitHub [**repository**](https://github.com/filip-adriginal/liferay-faces/tree/master/demos/bridge)!

Helped me with my problems out a lot!